# Naming APIs, to imply transfer of memory ownership?

Tags: c++11, naming-conventions, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, api-design

I have a data structure.  It provides APIs for adding or deleting items from its internal collection.  Internally, the structure uses `std::unique_ptr` to maintain the lifespan of each item.  This means that "adding" an item *implicitly* transfers ownership of the memory to my data structure.

I've documented this clearly in the comments for this API, but I was wondering; is there a de-facto name or verb I can attach to my API, to call attention to this important side-effect?

For instance: `AddItem(Item* item)` does not seem to adequately imply transfer of ownership.  `RegisterItem`, `CreateItem`, `TransferItem` all seem to imply something different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to communicate the transfer of ownership is to use a `std::unique_ptr` as the argument:

```
AddItem(std::unique_ptr<Item> item)
```

Comment: That that if your API needs to admit the possibility of using a different `std` library implementation than the client, this requires extra work.  (You'd have a shim layer and a binary stable API layer)

Comment: Easier: `namespace library{ namespace private_abi { void AddItem( Item* item ); } inline void AddItem( std::unique_ptr<Item> item ) { private_abi::AddItem(item.release()); } }`  No need to reimplement it, you pass it through a narrow shim that uses C-style bindings.  On the inside, the `private_abi::AddItem` rebinds it to a unique ptr.

Comment: @Yakk oh, nice. Much simpler :)